# What's the meaning of "parlor suite"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> All the trunks from that car there, twelve from here and the safe, to the parlor suite, rooms B-52, 54, 56.

From the dictionary, I know that *parlor* means *a room in a house which has comfortable chairs and is used for meeting guests*, this also means *parlor* is part of a house. But of course, *parlor suite* is a whole *suite*, not a part of a room. What's the meaning of it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here it is described:

> [Parlor](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/PARLOR) - A room in a private house/establishment where people can sit and talk and relax.
>
> [Suite](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/suite) - A set of room (as in hotel).

Now when it comes to parlor suite, it could be taken as a **comfortable and relaxing establishment** in a hotel (as we know Presidential Suite, Honeymoon Suite and so on).

[Parlor suite seems to be more spacious.](http://www.resortatredhawk.com/suite-descriptions.html) as most of the hotels highlight the 'space' there.

[Here is the example:](http://www.wynnlasvegas.com/Rooms/WynnTowerSuites/ParlorSuite)

[image: Parlor Suite in a Hotel of Las Vegas]

Comment: Not sure about the authenticity but it seems a valid description. *In some of the Parlor Suites, you can close off the bedroom and then there is a sitting/living room with a sofa that folds out into a flat bed, kind of like a futon.*

Comment: I wouldn't personally call the room in the picture above a parlor suite. The "Parlor Suite", along with the "Parlor Loft Suite", in the link you provided look more like it.

Comment: @DamkerngT.There are multiple photos of the room (and this looked beautiful!) and I had to post here *parlor suite* as it is. *Parlor Loft Suite* could have been considered as a different category.

Comment: I'm used to a parlor suite that has a parlor (a living section) in it, where the bedrooms are separate. The *Parlor Loft Suite* one appears to loft the parlor section, I think.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I mentioned it in my comment. However, get me the image so I can upload it to better support this answer.

Comment: I would use the one in that site myself, proclaiming the Fair Use. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Oh, you are talking about the previous link! That link is to show that **parlor suite are spacious.** The image shown below is taken from the hotel in Las Vegas where they don't have other images.

Comment: I followed the Las Vegas link and found a different photo! (which looks like a parlor section to me, possibly from the same suite).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible “parlor” is being used as an adjective to describe the suite, which has a parlor in it.

A similar but perhaps more common example would be the term [“sleeper cab”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_%28truck%29). “Cab” is short for “cabin” and describes the driver's compartment, and a “sleeper” is a compartment attached to the driver's compartment, designed for sleep. You'd refer to the whole thing as a “sleeper cab” even though the sleeper is a separate compartment.